# Update Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder

Tags: windows, dvd, windows-media-player, video-codecs, mpeg

When I see Technical Information for Windows media player. I can see information about `Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder (msmpeg2vdec.dll)`. In some machines I see version as `12.0.9200.16426` and some machines version is `6.1.7140.0`. There is a problem with a lower version in playing certain video files

1. Where to get this updated to latest version?
2. When I try to update media player which is having lower version, it says all are updated to latest.

I didn't see any official microsoft site having this codecs patch or updates.

Any Ideas?

Comment: On which machines did you see the newer files? Win8 with the Media Center Pack?

Comment: no windows 7 with windows media player 12.0.7601.17514

Comment: Perhaps they came via Windows Update?

Comment: I don't see any latest updates which is having the lower version

Comment: I don't think that `12.0.9200.16426` is a valid version number for `msmpeg2vdec.dll`, as that's a WMP version number and this file isn't part of WMP but of the Windows installation (the 6.1 version correctly stands for Windows 7). I also can't find any results for the 12.0.* version on http://support.microsoft.com, which should have a listing of all system file versions.

Comment: @TimDeBaets, But both versions are there in different windows7 machines. Is tat possible?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible, if some other application installed their own version of `msmpeg2vdec.dll`, perhaps a codec pack or even malware.